# Display Externally Retrieved Data within a Custom Template

Tags: filters, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to connect a firebase project to my wordpress site via a plugin. So far, using the `kreait/firebase-php` package, I'm able to retrieve the data that I want from the plugin and `var_dump` it into my wordpress installation.

I'd like to combine an externally sourced collection from firestore - i.e. `cars` - to wordpress `http://wordpress-url/cars/$CAR_ID`.

From what I can tell, it seems like I use `add_rewrite_rule` to get the templating done, but I'm stuck on how to add a handler for this rewrite rule to actually retrieve the data and add it to `the_post()` so that it's possible to actually render it from wordpress.

Is this where `add_filter` comes in?

I have this so far:

```php
add_action('init', 'register_rewrite_rules');
function register_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^cars/(?)$', 'index.php?pagename=car&car_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```